# AR Method to JSON

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have a Model

```
class Store
    has_many :opening_times
    #returns ActiveRecordRelation
```

i have an JSON API which calls something like

```
Store.first.opening_times.to_json
```

is there a way to make this method custom?

of course i know that i can make a method like "opening_times_to_json" and call that in my json template, but maybe there is a nice Ruby or Rails way that a method can response to different formats?

***EDIT***

i want it like that

and i did it now :

```
def opening_times_as_json
  #opening_times.map{|o| {o.weekday.to_sym=>"#{o.open} - #{o.close}"}}
  { :monday=>"#{opening_times[0].open} - #{opening_times[0].close}", 
    :tuesday=>"#{opening_times[1].open} - #{opening_times[1].close}",
    :wednesday=>"#{opening_times[2].open} - #{opening_times[2].close}",
    :thursday=>"#{opening_times[3].open} - #{opening_times[3].close}",
    :friday=>"#{opening_times[4].open} - #{opening_times[4].close}",
    :satturday=>"#{opening_times[5].open} - #{opening_times[5].close}",
    :sunday=>"#{opening_times[6].open} - #{opening_times[6].close}" }
end
```

which is the result what i want:

[image: Result]

is there a more elegant way to realise that?

```
opening_time model has weekday as string, open as integer and close as integer
```

## EDIT 2 as request opening_time model

```
class Advertisement::OpeningTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :weekday, :open, :close  
  belongs_to :advertisement
end
```

and the advertisement

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :opening_times
    def initialize(*params)super(*params)
    if (@new_record)
      %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday firday saturday sunday).each do |weekday|
        self.opening_times.build weekday: weekday
      end      
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post `OpenTime` model code?

Comment: updated the post with the models

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can override `as_json` method of `OpeningTime` model. Here is the [article on as_json vs to_json](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/). Quote: "as_json is used to create the structure of the JSON as a Hash, and the rendering of that hash into a JSON string is left up to ActiveSupport::json.encode. You should never use to_json to create a representation, only to consume the representation."

So, you would do something like:

```
class OpeningTime

  def as_json(options)
    super(:only => [:attributes_you_want], :methods => [:description_markdown])
  end

end
```

**UPDATE**

Have you tried following in your controller:

class StoreOpeningTimes < ApplicationController

```
 def index
   @store = Store.find(params[:id])
   render json: @store.opening_times
 end
```

end

Hope, it helps.

Comment: hey simon,i edited my question. maybe you want to have a look again.

Answer (score 1):

I might recommend something like this:

```
DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday"
]

# I might recommend renaming #opening_times_as_json to #hours
def hours
  DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK.map { |day| :day.to_sym => hours_for_day(day) }
end

def hours_for_day(day)
  "#{opening_times[index_for_day(day)].open} - #{opening_times[index_for_day(day)].close}"
end

def index_for_day(day)
  DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK.index(day_of_week_name)
end
```